# Delete a row from DB

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp

i have a simple web application in which you can book a room. Now when someone books a room i want give the possibility to delete the reservation. 
I have created a jsp file:

> cancel.jsp

with this code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>
<%
String id=request.getParameter("cid");
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HotelReservation", "root", "123456789");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
int i=st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE cid="+id);
out.println("Data Deleted Successfully!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.print(e);
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

and in booked.jsp :

```
<%  while(rs.next())
        {

           int id = rs.getInt("cid");

          //  out.println(id);
            String cname  = rs.getString("cname");
           // out.println(cname);
            String email  = rs.getString("email");
            String arrival  = rs.getString("arrival_date");
            String departure  = rs.getString("departure_date");
            int person  = rs.getInt("person");
            int room  = rs.getInt("room");
            String type_room = rs.getString("type_room");



            %> 

            <div class="hotel-block"  style="background-color: #5882FA;padding: 2px 15px 30px;margin-top: -20px; width: 102%; margin-left: -23px;">
                ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
                <h2 class="heading"><label style=" margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 151px;">Name :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 200px;"><%out.println(cname);%></h2> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">Email :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 200px;"><%out.println(email);%></span></h3> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">arrival date :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 100px;"><%out.println(arrival);%></h2>
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">departure date:</label><span  style=" margin-left: 50px;"><%out.println(departure);%></h2> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">no. of person :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 70px;"><%out.println(person);%></h2>
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">no. of room :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 100px;"><%out.println(room);%></h2> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">type room:</label><span  style=" margin-left: 100px;"><%out.println(type_room);%></h2>

               <form action='cancel.jsp'>
               <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<%=("id") %>">
             <input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'>

            </form>
           </div>
```

Also i have the table in my DB: hotel_booking with this parameters:

> cid(INT,Primary key,not null, autoincrement); cname; email; arrival_date; departure_date;....

I don't understand how can i do to delete a particular reservation. Every times that someone books a room automatically cid increment by one. 
Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<%=("id") %>">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<%= id%>">
```

Comment: @Keyz23 : Please, can you mark this answer as solution if it helped you :)